# Is the function $f(x) = e^x \cos (1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $A = (0,1)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

The question and its answer is given below:

Determine whether t the function $f(x) = e^x \cos (1/x)$ is uniformly continuous on $A = (0,1)$.

> [image]

but I am wondering why the $n$ is chosen like this, and if it should be $N$? and why $1/n\pi$ is $\leq \delta?$ could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: No it is not a duplicate @LordSharktheUnknown  my questions are different in both posts.

Comment: That only works if $n$ is an odd positive integer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .... but this is not an answer to my questions.@LordSharktheUnknown .... or at least I can not see that it is answer

Comment: It demonstrates that the "answer" you reproduce is incorrect. The "answers at the back of the book" are usually produced as an afterthought, with little care. Take them with a pinch of salt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the proof. If you take $n=[\frac 1 {\delta \pi}]+1$ the proof works fine because $n >\frac 1 {\delta \pi}$ in this case , so $\frac 1 {n\pi} <\delta$.

Comment: you mean n = floor function +1?

Comment: And so the given proof can be corrected if it is $N$ not $n$. correct?

Comment: But How he thought about this value and what about the $\delta$ ?

Comment: You also need to ensure that $n$ is odd.

Comment: @hopefully The above proof says that $e^x \cos (1/x)$ has NO limit as $x\to 0^+$ and therefore it can not be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @hopefully The choice of the points $x$ and $y$ is quite natural and it comes from properties of $\cos$. Once you choose these points you get $|x-y|=\frac 1 {6n \pi}$. To make this less than   $\delta$ you need $n>\frac 1 {6\pi \delta}$. That is, you need an integer that exceeds $\frac 1 {6\pi \delta}$. Natural choice would be the smallest integer greater than this number. This is what they have did except that they use $1/6 <1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown   why I need to ensure that?

Comment: @hopefully if $n$ is even then $\cos(3n\pi)=1$.

Comment: Correct Thank you @RobertZ

Comment: But how can you see Kavi that the above proof says that the given function has no limit as $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$?

Comment: I don't know why you are bringing in unnecessary things into the argument. To prove that the function is not uniformly continuous they are assuming it is uniformly continuous, applying the defintion, and arriving at a contradiction. Why bother about extending the function to $[0,1]$?

Comment: Sorry it was not your comment Kavi .... I am so sorry